# How to replace "\" and "\\" for only a specific tag in XML?

Tags: c#

I am trying to match the `Location` tag in an XML and replace "\" with  "\\" in the xml content only for the Location tag ,can anyone provide guidance on how to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Matchlocationreplacebackslash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = "<Location>(.*?)</Location>";
            string xmlcontent = @"<SoftwareProductBuild>
                        <BuildSource>QCA_DEV_POSTCOMMIT</BuildSource>
                        <BuiltBy>wbibot</BuiltBy>
                        <CreatedBy>wbibot</CreatedBy>
                        <Name>BTFM.CHE.2.1.2-00091-QCACHROM-1_NO_VARIANT</Name>
                        <Status>Approved</Status>
                        <BuiltOn>2017-08-28T13:00:04.345Z</BuiltOn>
                        <Tag>BTFM.CHE.2.1.2_BTFM.CHE.2.1.2-00091-QCACHROM-1_2017-08-28T13:00:04.345Z</Tag>
                        <SoftwareImageBuilds>
                            <SoftwareImageBuild>
                                <Type>LA</Type>
                                <Name>BTFM.CHE.2.1.2-00091-QCACHROM-1_NO_VARIANT</Name>
                                <Location>\\snowcone\builds676\INTEGRATION\BTFM.CHE.2.1.2-00091-QCACHROM-1</Location>
                                <Variant>NO_VARIANT</Variant>
                                <LoadType>Direct</LoadType>
                                <Target>NO_VARIANT</Target>
                                <SoftwareImages>
                                    <SoftwareImage>
                                        <Name>BTFM.CHE.2.1.2</Name>
                                        <SoftwareProducts>
                                            <SoftwareProduct>
                                                <Name>MSM8998.LA.1.9</Name>
                                                <BaseMeta>CI_MSM8998.LA.1.9-16991-INT-2</BaseMeta>
                                            </SoftwareProduct>
                                        </SoftwareProducts>
                                    </SoftwareImage>
                                </SoftwareImages>
                            </SoftwareImageBuild>
                        </SoftwareImageBuilds>
                    </SoftwareProductBuild>";
            Match match = Regex.Match(xmlcontent, pattern); //Match location
            //Replace "\" with  "\\" in the xml content with the match
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clearly state the requirement. _and replace "\" with "\" ..._ They're both the same.

Comment: I think the title of the issue has it, in that he wants a single slash replaced with double-slash.  Our text editors here may be processing that out strangely.   As for the problem, this feels like a "use LINQ to traverse the XML and change what you want in-place" kind of problem.

Comment: It is an anomaly in the SO editor - \\ appears a \.  You need to type \\\ to get \\

Comment: I sugget find specific tag using, for example `XPath`, and replace "\" directly for him.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria - Can you provide a specific example on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regex. Use a xml parser like [Linq2Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlcontent);
foreach(var loc in xDoc.Descendants("Location"))
{
    loc.Value = loc.Value.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
}

string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

*PS: A good SO post to read. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlcontent);
var locations = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Location");
foreach (XmlNode location in locations)
{
    var newLocation = location.InnerText.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    location.InnerText = newLocation;
}
```

If you need your `xmlcontent` be updated then you can write:

```
xmlcontent = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```